# Support mutiple screens in android 3.2 and lesser

Tags: android, screen-size

I have just started supporting multiple screen sizes for my app and found that it is differently handled in devices targeted at Android release 3.2 and for devices with lesser version.
Is is possible to make an app compatible for all SDK versions greater > 1.6 (including 3.2 are greater)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Mutiple apk Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html) if your apk size exceeds 50MB.  Otherwise you can use Android Compatibility package which is available with Android.